# Что неправильно работает в правиле при формировании ссылки?

Tags: yii2

Есть ссылка, которая формируется так:

```
$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/actours/actour','slug'=>$actours->slug_name])
```

Вот правило, которое роутит ссылку:

```
'actours/<slug>'=>'actours/actour',
```

Получается такая ссылка:

```
sites.lc/actours/Luk-Uilson
```

Но вот такая ссылка тоже роутится

```
sites.lc/actours/actour?id=1549
```

Как мне правильно написать правило так, чтобы нижняя ссылка не под правило не подпадала?

Comment: Скорее всего, для нижней ссылки необходимо прописать отдельно правило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отключть дефолтный роутинг укажите в параметрах компоненты `urlManager` опцию [`enableStrictParsing`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enableStrictParsing-detail):

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
```